# Binomial Heaps: proof that merge runs in O(log n) time

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, functional-programming, big-o, ml

I am reading through [Okasaki's Purely Functional Data Structures](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/theses/okasaki.pdf) and am trying to do some of the exercises. One of them is to prove that binomial heap `merge` takes `O(log n)` time where `n` is the number of nodes in the heap.

```
functor BinomialHeap (Element:ORDERED):HEAP=
struct
  structure Elem=Element
  datatype Tree = Node of int*Elem.T*Tree list
  type Heap = Tree list
  fun link (t1 as Node (r,x1,c1), t2 as Node (_,x2,c2))=
    if Elem.leq(x1,x2)
    then Node (r+1,x1,t2::c1)
    else Node (r+1,x2,t1::c2)
  fun insTree (t,[])=[t]
     |insTree (t,ts as t'::ts')=
        if rank t < rank t' then t::ts else insTree(link(t,t'),ts')
  fun insert (x,ts)=insTree(Node(0,x,[]),ts) (*just for reference*)
  fun merge (ts1,[])=ts1
     |merge ([],ts2)=ts2
     |merge (ts1 as t1::ts1', ts2 as t2:ts2')=
        if rank t1 < rank t2 then t1::merge(ts1',ts2)
        else if rank t2 < rank t1 then t2::merge(ts1,ts2')
        else insTree (link(t1,t2), merge (ts1',ts2'))
end
```

It is clear that `merge` will call itself `max(numNodes ts1, numNodes ts2)` times, but since `insTree` is `O(log n)` worst case, can you explain how `merge` is `O(log n)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note that `merge` will be called at most `(numNodes ts1 + numNodes ts2)` times, and this is `O(log n)` times. (Just to be clear, `ts1` and `ts2` are lists of binomial trees, where such a tree of rank `r` contains exactly `2^r` nodes, and each rank can occur at most once. Therefore, there are `O(log n1)` such trees in `ts1` and `O(log n2)` in `ts2`, where `n1` and `n2` are the number of nodes in the heaps and `n=n1+n2`.)

The key point to notice is that `insTree` is called at most once for each rank (either through `merge` or recursively), and the largest possible rank is `log_2(n)`. The reason is the following:

If `insTree` is called from `merge`, then say `r = rank t1 = rank t2`, and `link(t1,t2)` will have rank `r+1`. So let's say `insTree` is called for rank `r+1`. Now think about what happens with `merge(ts1', ts2')`. Let the smallest rank that occurs as a tree in `ts1'` *and* `ts2'` be `r' >= r+1`. Then `insTree` will be called again from `merge` for rank `r'+1`, since the two trees of rank `r'` will get linked to form a tree of rank `r'+1`. However, the merged heap `merge(ts1', ts2')` can therefore *not* contain a tree of rank `r'`, and the previous call to `insTree` can therefore not recurse further than `r'`.

So putting things together:

- `insTree` is called at most `O(log n)` times, with each call being constant time (since we count the recursion as a separate call)
- `merge` is called at most `O(log n)` times, with each call being constant time (since we count the calls to `insTree` separately and `link` is constant time)

=> The entire merge operation is `O(log n)`.

EDIT: By the way, merging binomial heaps is very much like adding binary numbers. A heap of size `n` will have a tree of rank `r` if and only if the binary number `n` has a '1' at the `2^r` position. When merging such heaps, you proceed from the lowest rank to highest rank -- or least significant to most significant position. Trees of the same rank need to be linked (the 'ones' added), and inserted / "carried" into the higher rank positions.

Comment: Can you expand on this:  "However, the merged heap `merge(ts1', ts2')` can therefore not contain a tree of rank <= `r'`". I believe it can if `ts1` has a tree of rank `r'` and `ts2` does not contain a tree of `r'`.

Comment: Forget the "<= `r'`", if should be just `r'` (just fixed that). `r'` is chosen as the smallest rank for which there is a tree in `ts1'` *and* `ts2'`. These trees get merged (form a rank `r'+1` tree), so in the merged heap `merge(ts1', ts2')`, there no longer is a tree of rank `r'`. The previous call to `insTree` can recurse for some ranks (namely as you say, as long as either `ts1'` or `ts2'` contain a tree of such a rank), but this recursion must stop latest at rank `r'`. Also, the next call to `insTree` from `merge` occurs at rank `r'+1`. So `insTree` is called at most once for each rank.